# Count number of pairs of elements in an array whose bitwise OR is equal to a given integer

Tags: algorithms, bit-manipulation

Given an integer array and an integer $k$, we have to count the number of pairs of elements from the array whose bitwise OR is $k$ in $O(n)$ time complexity. How could this be done?

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Equivalent: https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/79843/str-editorial

Comment: Can you credit the original source where you encountered this problem?